# iOS - viewForAnnotation return without executing

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I have the following code executing when an UI element is tapped:

```
- (IBAction)setPoint
{
    UserAnnotationView *pinview = (UserAnnotationView*)[self.map viewForAnnotation:currentAnnotation];
    NSLog(@"droping it: %@", pinview);
    NSLog(@"stop! hammer time!");
}
```

My `viewForAnnotation` looks like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
    NSLog(@"here !!!");
    ...
    ...
}
```

So, I expect the output in the console to be:

```
here !!!
droping it: <some object representation>
stop! hammer time!
```

But instead, I have this:

```
2012-12-07 18:03:58.506 MyApp[16523:707] droping it: (null)
2012-12-07 18:03:58.507 MyApp[16523:707] stop! hammer time!
2012-12-07 18:03:58.607 MyApp[16523:707] here!!!
```

How come the `viewForAnnotation` return immediately without executing and then executes correctly afterwards ?!?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewForAnnotation` is not something you are supposed to call yourself. It's what the map asks of its delegate when it needs to refresh its drawing. You are calling `viewForAnnotation` on your `MKMapView`, not a something that implements the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol (your `viewController` probably implements that) so you get `null` as a response. Then something else triggers the map to redraw and it asks its delegate for an annotation, which is when it prints out `here!!!`.